# Visual Studio dies when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fatal-error

When opening a particular solution in VS2012, the process is killed.  Event viewer shows Error 1026

Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelper.CleanupListener()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelper.Finalize()

Any ideas of cause?

EDIT

I do seem to be able to open other solutions.  Just trying to reinstall .NET framework.  Will try deleting the SUO file if that doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried deleting the suo file?

Comment: Are you able to open other solutions? What's different about _this_ one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio and it fixed this